# Disable permission in android

Tags: android, permissions

I want to create Application which disable other application permission. for example I Don’t want Facebook or Viber to access my location. there are 2 application (in my knowledge) which can do something like this

1.this is a open source application.

https://github.com/slvn/android-appops-launcher

but this is not for all android version.

2. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.pmaster&hl=en

so my question is how can i disable other application permission?
please guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: thank you all down voters. this is my fault to not having knowledge and asking question here.

Comment: wut? of course it's your fault to not having knowledge, whos else... you are trying create app (probably?) without knowledge about system and its behaviours... you have found ready and steady code, you know limitation of os version and instead of searching why these limitations even exists you are asking for code us (stack community). and where is your code? have you tried anything besides searching in Google for ready code? read some FAQ or regulation and then you will find out why you get these down votes (question should be precise and present some tries for resolving)

Comment: @snachmsm whatever i asked here is just 1% of my app. and there are many way to solve my problem, i was asking for some ideas, and no os limitation can stop me for doing whatever i want to do.

Comment: when you omit os limitations and develop your custom App Ops app which will not require root (might be only for >=4.4.3, below 4.3 isn't interesting me) please let me know, I'll be using your product :)

Comment: ok sure.. i will  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have source, what else you want?

App Ops were introduced in 4.3 and were disabled/removed in 4.4.3. You can't change permissions in other versions of system, because these options are simply not present there (before 4.3 and above 4.4.2, including 4.4.3 and 4.4.4).

Thats why this linked app is "not for all android version". Some of them (these with root) porting these methods from original App Ops or are using present, hidden in system. In >=4.4.3 it needs root permission level for execution.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly impossible without rooting, and shouldn't be possible afterwards (though it seems it is)

Basically, when you install an app, you accept the permissions it needs. Something as a terms and conditions.